# Retrieve custom domain associated to deleted WebApp on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, domain, web

A resource group was deleted and their was an associated custom domain that was purchased in azure. How do I retrieve this domain and associate it to a new WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

If you still use the same subscription to create a new Webapp, you can easy to find the app services Domains in the web app's **Custom domains** page. If you cannot see it in the web app's Custom domains page, try reopening the Custom domains page or refresh the webpage. Also, check the notification bell at the top of the Azure portal for progress or creation failures.

Moreover, in Azure, DNS records for an App Service Domain are managed using Azure DNS. You can follow the path to select the domain to manage. In the Azure portal, from the left menu, select All services > App Service Domains.

Ref: [Assign hostnames to web app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app#assign-hostnames-to-web-app)

Comment: Please let me know if this helps.